# Surprising behavior with unicode dict keys

Tags: python, dictionary, unicode, ipython

Consider the following piece of code:

```
In [1]: a = {'ϵ': 1}

In [2]: b = dict(ϵ=1)

In [3]: a == b
Out[3]: False

In [4]: print(a, b)
{'ϵ': 1} {'ε': 1}
```

I was surprised to find out that `a` is not equal to `b`. It appears that the resulting dicts use distinct Unicode symbols for epsilon, despite having similar definitions (I type `\epsilon` + tab in my IPython environment).

I wonder why this happens and if there is a preferred way to handle Unicode keys in this situation.

Comment: `dict(ϵ=1)` gives me `SyntaxError`.

Comment: @bro-grammer I guess I should mention that I use Python 3. I do not get a syntax error.

Comment: I am also using python 3. `dict([('ϵ',1)])` works for me.

Comment: Strange. I guess the identifier issue covers my question, though I am not sure why there is a difference in SyntaxError behavior.

Comment: In the form `dict(ϵ=1)`, `ϵ` is an identifier so it is normalized to NFKC. In other words it is equivalent to `dict(ε=1)`. On the other hand, in `dict([('ϵ',1)])` the `'ϵ'` is a string.

Comment: Regarding the syntax error that is probably an artefact of characters getting mangled. If I type this in on a Windows console, the limitations of that console turn it into `dict(?=1)`.

Comment: @bro-grammer What version of 3.x are you using? If it's pre-3.6, is your locale non-UTF-8? (Or are you on Windows?) And did you test in a script, or a REPL? And, if a REPL, the standard on or iPython or otherwise, and in the terminal/console or something like IDLE? Because it should do exactly what the OP is seeing, but on Windows, or pre-3.6 on many Linux systems, etc., it may not.

Comment: (Well, "should" from a certain point of view. The Unicode standard, like some Jedi Masters, can be a bit inscrutable.)

Comment: @abarnert yes it turns out locale is non-UTF-8. Thanks for pointing out it was very helpful!